# the \percent macro is not working in siunitx package

Tags: beamer, siunitx

I get error when I use the `\percent` macro in the `siunitx` package. Here is the code :

```
              \documentclass[]{beamer}
              \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
              \usepackage{siunitx}
              \setbeamercolor{title}{bg=red!65!black,fg=white}
              \begin{document}
              \title{Risk Management in Software Engineering}
              \author{S.Subham Soni}
              \institute[P.E.C]{Department of Computer Science and Engineering\\
 Pondicherry Engineering College}
              \date{January 6, 2014}     
              \begin{frame}
              \begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
              \hline
              \textbf{Risk}&\textbf{Percentage} \\
              \hline
               Very Low&$\textless10\%$ \\
               \hline
               Low&10\percent-25\percent \\
               \hline
             \end{tabular}
             \end{frame}
             \end{doccument}
```

Here the `\percent` is throwing the error as symbol not found. The code is a part of the full code so there might be some continuation gap....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use it like `\si{\percent}` (or `\SI{10}{\percent}`)

```
          \documentclass[]{beamer}
          \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
          \usepackage{siunitx}
          \setbeamercolor{title}{bg=red!65!black,fg=white}
          \begin{document}
          \title{Risk Management in Software Engineering}
          \author{S.Subham Soni}
          \institute[P.E.C]{Department of Computer Science and Engineering\\
             Pondicherry Engineering College}
          \date{January 6, 2014}
          \begin{frame}
          \begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
          \hline
          \textbf{Risk}&\textbf{Percentage} \\
          \hline
           Very Low&$<\SI{10}{\percent}$ \\
           \hline
           Low& 10\si{\percent}--25\si{\percent} \\
           \hline
         \end{tabular}
         \end{frame}
         \end{document}
```

There was a typo in `end{document}`. Further, if you intend to put a range like `10-25%`, better use `\SIrange[range-phrase = --]{10}{25}{\percent}`. And don't use `\textless` in math mode, use `<` instead.

Comment: Why should you use \percent at all? Is there any advantage of `$\SI{12.3}{\percent}$` over `$12.3\%$`?

Comment: @moose The spacing between the number and symbol. `siunitx` is good in keeping that correct space.  See Joseph's answer about spacing below.

Comment: Please note that ISO 80000-1 says you should use `10 % - 25 %` as @user11232 and @Mico suggested with the `\SIrange` command.

Answer (score 4):

Harish has given what I would say is the ['standard position' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152949): using the `\si`/`\SI` commands is by far the best way to use `siunitx`. However, you can use 'free standing' units, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[free-standing-units, space-before-unit, use-xspace]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\percent} or perhaps 10\percent water.
\end{document}
```

Getting spacing correct in this case can be tricky: I would strongly recommend using Harish's approach if possible.